# HL7-Fhir : Nested (child) resources and _include supported/allowed in read result from a single resource

Tags: hl7-fhir

This [page](http://hl7-fhir.github.io/http.html#read) describes the simple read.

However it's not clear to me if **_include** ([web-page](https://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/FHIR/search.html#return)) is supported (see chapter 2.2.4.1 Include Paths) and if **nested resource(s)** can also be returned ?

So is the following request :
https://example.com/MedicationOrder/5?_include=MedicationOrder.medication valid ?

And should the json-response be like:

```
{
  "resourceType": "MedicationOrder",
  "id": "5",
  "detail" : "abc",
  "medication":
  {
      "resourceType": "Medication",
      "id": "example",
      "otherDetails": "xyz"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

_include is only supported as part of a search. So

https://example.com/MedicationOrder/5?_include=MedicationOrder.medication

is not valid. This is:

https://example.com/MedicationOrder?_id=5&_include=MedicationOrder:medication

Then you get back a bundle with the MedicationOrder and the medication, if there is one.

What you call 'nested resources' - do you mean contained resources? - well, if there are contained resources in the MedicationOrder, they they are always returned with it - they are part of it. But they don't appear in the medication as you show in the example above. Instead:

```
{
  "resourceType": "MedicationOrder",
  "id": "5",
  "detail" : "abc",
  "medication": { 
    "reference" : "#m1"
  },
  "contained": [
    {
      "resourceType": "Medication",
      "id": "m1",
      "otherDetails": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To be clear, the json-response you posted here should be the response on a single GET, like https://example.com/MedicationOrder/5